# Looking for a way to build a scala immutable.TreeMap from a list

Tags: scala, treemap

So far the only way I can figure is using:

```
var ans: TreeMap[Int, Int] = immutable.TreeMap(List(1,2,3).map(e => (e, e*2)): _*)
```

1) Is there a way to do it without using the vararg _* syntax?

2) Is this pattern a good practice in scala?

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is there a way to do it without using the vararg _* syntax?

Yes, you can use `breakOut` parameter to `map`. Note that this requires explicit type annotation on variable

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

val ans: TreeMap[Int, Int] = List(1,2,3).map(e => (e, e*2))(breakOut)
```

> 2) Is this pattern a good practice in scala?

Until collections in Scala 2.13 allow you to write `list.to(TreeMap)`, it's fine. I mean, it's not like there are better options, so use whatever solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do it without using the vararg _* syntax?

Since the `apply` method on `TreeMap` takes vararg of type `(A, B)*`, I don't see any other built in way

> Is this pattern a good practice in scala?

I don't see why it wouldn't be.

An alternative would be to provide an extension method in the form of `toTreeMap` map which could work.

Answer (score 1):

1) The other way would be creating an empty TreeMap and then adding all elements:

```
immutable.TreeMap.empty[Int, Int] ++ (List(1,2,3).map(e => (e, e*2)))
```

I don't have strong feelings about which way is better.

2) Yes, this is fairly common.

Comment: Hah, I somehow always forget you can `++` a list to a map.